# Datagridview fills on second attempt. Never first attempt in Tab Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a tab list where each tab has its own "x" amount of datagridviews. For some reason the first active tab fills the datagridviews just fine. When I click on the second tab in the Tab Control, the datagridviews fill the data but the gridview shows empty *[When I followed the code it showed the records being filled into the datagridview]*.

If I click to another tab and then back to the second tab the gridview refills again and then shows the data. Does anyone know what may cause this? It is always the first attempt that never initially fills the other tabs [aside the first active tab]

Comment: `the datagridviews fill the data but the gridview shows empty`  That seems impossible.  Since there are "x" DGVs make sure you are filling the right one

Comment: I am filling the correct one. I do `mydatagrid.Rows.Add()` and add my own rows. I even do a `Rows.Count` and see the records were added and yet it display empty. I click another tab and then back to the one that displayed empty... code runs trough again to fill and then displays the records. Craziest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: please read [ask]... no piece of code?  seriously? how r we supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: I didn't have code aside the comment I made of `Rows.Add` that would be applicable since I was only asking if anything may cause this reaction to happen for datagridview

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can tell... nested Datagridviews can't be dynamically filled at first load using `myDataGrid.Rows.Add(.....)`. The only way I was able to do this on first load was to build a Datatable and fill that instead. Can't understand why but it works....

```
With myDataGrid
        Dim f As Font = .Font
        .Columns.Clear()
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .DataMember = Nothing
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        '.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells
        .Columns(0).Name = "MsgID"
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "MsgID"
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "MsgID"
        .Columns(0).Visible = False
        .Columns(1).Name = "Message"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Message"
        .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Message"
        .Columns(2).Name = "Sig"
        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Sig"
        .Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Sig"
        .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        .Font = New Font(f, FontStyle.Bold)
        .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 1
        .Refresh()
End With



Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("MsgID")
dt.Columns.Add("Message")
dt.Columns.Add("Sig")
dt.Columns(0).AutoIncrement = True

With ArrMessages(x)
    Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    R(0) = .MsgID
    R(1) = .Msgs
    R(2) = .Sig
    dt.Rows.Add(R)
End With

'assign sourcing
 myDataGrid.DataSource = dt
 myDataGrid.Refresh()
 Me.myDataGrid.Parent.Refresh()
 myDataGrid.Refresh()
```

Comment: `nested Datagridviews`??? the OP makes no mention of that - I'm not sure what it even means

Comment: nested within the tab control.